# Hide field without content for Dexterity content type

Tags: plone, dexterity

I created a content type with Dexterity, and after adding one item, 
on the front page the fields without content are still displayed in the details page.

I want to hide those fields and their title, what should I do?

Comment: You mean that the field label is still being displayed for fields?

Comment: yes, the field label is still there but no content

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the view of Dexterity types using a [display form](http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/manual/developer-manual/custom-views/display-forms).

This is a `z3c.form` form, so we can use the `.updateWidgets()` method to set the widget availability dynamically to [hide some of them](http://developer.plone.org/forms/z3c.form.html#hiding-fields):

```
import z3c.form
from plone.directives import dexterity

class MyCustomView(dexterity.DisplayForm):
    grok.context(IMyContentType)
    grok.require('zope2.View')

    def updateWidgets(self):
        super(MyCustomView, self).updateWidgets()
        for widget in self.widgets.values():
            if not widget.value:
                widget.mode = z3c.form.interfaces.HIDDEN_MODE
```

Comment: can I modify the default view? where is it ? I donot know how to create the custom view and which folder?

Comment: @BingquanBao: You'd either have to customize the `item.pt` template and find if any item is empty there, or you'd have to subclass the `DisplayForm` like we did here (which *is* the default view).

Comment: I want to hide the fieldset, what should I do    <fieldset tal:repeat="group view/groups"
              tal:attributes="id python:''.join((group.prefix, 'groups.', group.__name__)).replace('.', '-')">
        <legend tal:content="group/label" />
        <div class="field" tal:repeat="widget group/widgets/values">
            <label tal:content="widget/label" />
            <br />
            <div tal:content="structure widget/render" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>